# Repetir bucle al capturar Excepcion

Tags: java, excepciones

!Buenas!

Estoy intentando (en un código muy sencillo) que cuando el *usuario* escriba una letra o palabra en una variable que espera un **tipo numérico**, capturar el error con un `try catch` y que vuelva a repetir al usuario que introduzca algún numero.

Por ejemplo como en este código, para que me sirva como explicación...

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numero1;
        int numero2;
        int total;

        do {

            try {

                System.out.print("Introduce numero 1: ");
                numero1 = sc.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Introduce numero 2: ");
                numero2 = sc.nextInt();

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                System.out.println("No es un numero. Toma como valor 0. Repite");

                numero1 = 0;
                numero2 = 0;
            }

            total = numero1 + numero2;

            System.out.println("Total: " + total);

        } while (total <= 0);

    }
}
```

Mi idea es que al introducir un dato **no numérico**, recoja el error y, en este caso, imprima un mensaje y de como valor a ambas variables: **0**. Para así, el total se iguale a **0**, y el bucle se active.

Pero con este ejemplo se vuelve un bucle infinito, y no estoy entendiendo bien el por que, ni el como hacer lo que quiero.

Me gustaría saber si de la forma en la que quiero solucionarlo es posible, o si hay alguna alternativa...

Un saludo :)

Comment: Si, pero me hace un bucle infinito. Repite el mensaje dentro del catch y no deja hacer nada mas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que cuando el usuario introduce un dato no numérico, ocurre el error, pero el mismo dato se queda en el *buffer* del `Scanner`, esperando ser leído. Al *cachar* el error, la ejecución retorna al inicio, pero el Scanner sigue en la misma posición, por lo que la siguiente llamada a `nextInt()` falla nuevamente, y se queda en un bucle infinito.

Puedes, dentro de tu manejador de excepción, llamar a `nextLine();` del `Scanner` para *ignorar* lo que haya introducido el usuario en esa línea e iniciar de nuevo, algo como:

```
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            System.out.println("No es un numero. Toma como valor 0. Repite");

            numero1 = 0;
            numero2 = 0;
            sc.nextLine();
        }
```

Ya con eso, tu programa volverá a la ejecución que esperas.

Comment: Que fallo no acordarme del buffer. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, funciona perfecto!